# Does it penalize sneak to have a weapon drawn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It's said that carrying a two-handed weapon increases your chances of being spotted when trying to sneak.

Does it penalize Sneaking to have a weapon merely drawn, or only when you attack?  Does the size/weight of the weapon make a difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Am I more easily detected while sneaking with a spell equipped?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36485/am-i-more-easily-detected-while-sneaking-with-a-spell-equipped)

Comment: @Ivo Flipse — That question addresses spells quite well, but not weapons.  I've editied this question to focus on weapons.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to point it out :-)

Answer (score 5):

yup i'm pretty sure it's based on weapon size. Back when I was raising sneak by sneak attacking the greybeards (hehe) they would immediatly detect me if it hit them with a sword, but not with a dagger.

Answer (score 2):

I think the bigger the weapon, the less stealthy you are, though I have not tested this. 
You could give it a go yourself: Save it at a point, and have in your inventory, a dagger, a sword, axe, warhammer etc. and give them all a go. Sneak up on people or a person.

You might just surprise yourself and have fun at the same time