# Does removing torches help my sneaking?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does light affect sneaking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37662/does-light-affect-sneaking)

It is often possible to take torches from walls in a dungeon. And since light affect sneaking, does picking up torches help?

Comment: I presume you mean picking them up and putting them into your inventory so that they are extinguished?  I'm pretty sure carried light sources (i.e.: flaming hands) don't affect Sneak.  But I don't know about removable, wall-mounted ones.

Comment: See also this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36485/am-i-more-easily-detected-while-sneaking-with-a-spell-equipped

Comment: @RavenDreamer I think this is a special case which may be worth exploring in more detail.  Could we re-open this, pending other close votes?

Comment: @Iszi I think the duplicate answers what this person is asking: "Yes, the level of light that you are currently standing in affects how easily you are spotted while sneaking." If you take a torch from the wall and extinguish it, then this answers that.

Comment: @DoozerBlake That's an easy presumption to make, but I (and I'm guessing the asker) think it would be interesting if someone on the PC (with access to the console, to view the appropriate variables) could test it.

Comment: @Iszi, I think there's no need to ask another question to determine this: we can accomplish the same thing by posting a comment on the answer to the existing question. That person (or someone else with a PC) can test and update, giving us a more well-rounded answer in the same place as the existing question.